# Boot stuck on logo screen after upgrading from 14.04 to 14.10

Tags: boot, 14.10

After upgrading from 14.04 to 14.10 my computer cannot boot anymore, it is stuck at the logo screen (with animated dots). I'm using Windows to post this question.

By displaying the boot process, I see that it is stuck at "Stopping log initial device creation". When I press Ctrl+Alt+F2, only a flickering dash appears, and I can't even log in.

[image]

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Try switching to a virtual console by pressing any of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F6</kbd>. You may see what you need: Error messages, et cetera.

Other than that, you don't really have enough information in your question to help out. I don't have enough karma to comment, but you should give it a shot and see if you can provide the relevant error messages, et cetera.

Even better, Google those error messages first.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question. Hope somebody can help.